# Adjust limits for ADC

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I have a Hall element that I want to read by an ADC (MSP430 ADC10).
The Hall element gives me a voltage within 0-Vcc, whereas the ADC can only sample 0-Vcc/2.

In reality, the lowest value to sample is likely somewhere between 0.3V-1.0V.

What would be the simplest circuit that would give me adjustable lower and higher limits?

A simple voltage divider would allow me to adjust the upper limit, but I fail to see how I could also adjust the lower limit.

The circuit below will only work if min = 0.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftaQk2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: Clarified: Vmin -> 0 (or near 0), Vcc -> Vcc/2

Comment: You can divide by 2, but does hall effect output or ADC need to be buffered? Normally you drive an ADC with a low impedance source under 1K ohms.

Comment: The Hall element has a built-in buffer. What do you mean by "divide by 2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sensor minimum output is 300 mV, then it can be subtracted from the output. Adjust scale to get results/2. It is neigh impossible to get 0.00 volts without a negative voltage to pull down residual positive voltages, such as +300 mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8yxnW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How about taking the next circuit (A simple voltage divider)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4f4b.jpg)
You get a voltage divider that, As long as Z1=Z2, Vout is exactly half of Vin.
Then sample it, and multyply by 2

Comment: That will only change the upper limit and is exactly what I proposed in my question. Sorry for not being clear about that. I need somewhere to adjust the lower limit as well.